# android binder driver

Tags: android, drivers, android-binder

I am trying to read Android source code to learn about binder, but I am not able to find the part of binder driver as described in the Android system architecture. Any idea where the binder code resides in Android source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binder driver can be found in the kernel source code:

It's location can vary depending on the source code you have access to. It is usually at :

> /kernel/drivers/misc/binder.c

Other binder reading :

- [Presentation on binders](http://blog.kmckk.com/archives/3676340.html)
- [Interview with Dianne](http://www.osnews.com/story/13674/Introduction_to_OpenBinder_and_Interview_with_Dianne_Hackborn)

Comment: Thanks Reno, I downloaded android source from android website, but I cannot find the directory you said, anyway, thanks very much

Comment: Maybe the source does not contain kernel code. If you only want to read it, [you can online](http://os1a.cs.columbia.edu/lxr/source/drivers/staging/android/binder.c?a=x86)

Comment: The binder driver is now in `drivers/staging/android/binder.c`